# @oneTomany: is it possible to get parent with not all children?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, nativequery

City entity has List of SynopticData.

```
    public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private List<SynopticData> synopticDataList;
}
```

Is it possible to get City with List of specific SynopticDates?
I have such a query:

```
@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City,Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM city c left join synoptic_data s on c.id=s.city_id
    where s.local_date_time=(select s.local_date_time from synoptic_data s where s.city_id=c.id order by local_date_time desc limit 1) and c.name=:cityName", nativeQuery = true)
    public City findCity(@Param("cityName") String name);
}
```

In MySql it works properly but in java, hibernated add its own queries and as a result i get city with list of all SynopticData.

Is it possible to get that result? What are possibilities?

Comment: Getting the list via the  association from City will always give you the full list. You can  however add a query to your SynopticData repository to return the relevant items.

Comment: You could create a method on your `City` class which would return a filtered list

Comment: @AlanHay this is what i did, but it doesnt work

Comment: How is that what you did? Your method returns a City. It needs to return a `List<SynopticData>`. Also, why are you writing a native query?

Comment: ok, i misunderstand, now i see your point. why not native query? i couln't see other way. so basically the way i wanted to make it won't work

Comment: Avoid native queries. This will give problems regarding the caching mechanism in hibernate and start flushing data at moments you don't want to disregarding the unit of work principle.